# Getting values from a map within an array in Velocity

Tags: velocity

I've got the following array ($persArray) (example values, not an actually project - am trying to teach myself velocity for my job)

[{userId=1, events=[{eventId=1, eventTitle=Event 1, eventType=a}, {eventId=2, eventTitle=Event 2, eventType=a}]},{userId=2, events=[{eventId=3, eventTitle=Event 3, eventType=c}, {eventId=4, eventTitle=Event 4, eventType=d}]}]

Each entry can contain a different amounts of events

What I want to achieve is to list all events for a user including the event type looking like this:

User: 1
A: Event 1
A: Event 2

User: 2
C: Event 3
D: Event 4

I managed to access the first "level" but no clue how to go deeper as I've only worked with fairly simple, not "nested" arrays so far.

```
    #foreach($person in $persArray)##
      User: $person.userId<br/>
      Events: $person.events<p></p>
    #end##
```

Which outputs:
User: 1
Events: [{eventId=1, eventTitle=Event 1, eventType=a}, {eventId=2, eventTitle=Event 2, eventType=a}]

I've tried another foreach loop within the current one but that didn't work at all.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please share your failing code of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

A simple nested `foreach` loop on `$person.events` worked for me.

**Template:**

```
#foreach($person in $persArray)
    User: $person.userId<br/>
    Events: $person.events<p></p>

    #foreach($event in $person.events)
        Event: $event
    #end
#end
```

**Output:** (Using the same array in the question)

```
User: 1<br/>
    Events: [{eventId=1, eventTitle=Event 1, eventType=a}, {eventId=2, eventTitle=Event 2, eventType=a}]<p></p>

Event: {eventId=1, eventTitle=Event 1, eventType=a}
Event: {eventId=2, eventTitle=Event 2, eventType=a}
User: 2<br/>
    Events: [{eventId=3, eventTitle=Event 3, eventType=c}, {eventId=4, eventTitle=Event 4, eventType=d}]<p></p>

Event: {eventId=3, eventTitle=Event 3, eventType=c}
Event: {eventId=4, eventTitle=Event 4, eventType=d}
```